# How to configure SSL enabled Cassandra cluster as backend storage for cassandra-reaper?

Tags: kubernetes, cassandra, datastax

I have deployed Cassandra reaper as a stateful set in kubernetes cluster using latest docker image of it, to maintain Cassandra cluster. I have used Cassandra as a backend storage to store reaper data; which is working fine.

Just wanted to know how we can integrate ssl enabled Cassandra cluster to store reaper data. I have seen a template file `cassandra-reaper-cassandra-ssl.yaml`, which shows that need to add `ssl:type:jdk`, which I didn't get properly. Do I have to specify my ssl certificate location also in this section.

Also have seen after the deployment, and logging to pod showing me one env variable `REAPER_CASS_NATIVE_PROTOCOL_SSL_ENCRYPTION_ENABLED` which is having default value as `false`, **do I need to use this entry and make it as `true`?**

Comment: Just acknowledging your question. I've pinged the Cassandra Reaper team and will get you a response soon. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks Eric for response, able to resolve this. We have to set value of this environment variable as true in manifest file. REAPER_CASS_NATIVE_PROTOCOL_SSL_ENCRYPTION_ENABLED=true. Apart from that also need to add cert location keystore and truststore for ssl communication.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do have to set `REAPER_CASS_NATIVE_PROTOCOL_SSL_ENCRYPTION_ENABLED` to true, which [will set the ssl:type:jdk for you](https://github.com/thelastpickle/cassandra-reaper/blob/2.0.5/src/server/src/main/docker/configure-persistence.sh#L48-L53) in the container.
Then, you need to [set the `JAVA_OPTS` env variable](https://github.com/thelastpickle/cassandra-reaper/blob/2.0.5/src/server/src/main/docker/Dockerfile#L72) on the container which will allow you to set the truststore and keystore location and passwords:

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=/path/to/keystore.jks
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=keystore_password
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/path/to/truststore.jks
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=truststore_password
```

With this, you should be able to use a cluster that uses client encryption to store Reaper data.